# how to form rules with frequent itemsets using mahout

Tags: data-mining, mahout

I am learning fpgrowth in mahout, I find the function of birth  frequent itemsets, but  how to form rules with frequent itemsets using mahout? doesn't it implement in mahout yet?

Answer (score 0):

Computing the rules from the frequent patterns is fairly easy, and probably doesn't benefit a lot from parallelism and distributed. After all, it is expected that you get a much lower number of frequent patterns out of your data.

So it may be a lot faster to do that outside of Mahout, depending on the amount of frequent patterns that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Mahout is not specialised for pattern mining.

You can check the SPMF software : http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php (I'm the author).

It has Java source code for more than 45 algorithms related to frequent itemset and association rule mining.

It include algorithms for some classic algorithms like FPGrowth. But it also offers several specialized algorithms that you won't find in other data mining tools like for mining rare itemset, erasable itemsets, high-utility itemsets, itemsets from uncertain data, etc. etc.

For example, there are many different types of association rules that you can try beside the "classic" association rules such as : closed association rules, informative and generic basic of association rules, sequential rules, etc. etc.

It is licensed under the GPL and there is a simple GUI interface for some of the most popular algorithms and if you have any question you can post in the forum and i will try to answer you.

Comment: In mahout, there is only what they call "Parallel FP-Growth" for finding itemsets. There is no algorithms for generating the association rules after the itemsets are found. If you want to find rules with Mahout, you would need to implement it by yourself.  Besides,  note that what they call "Parallel FPGrowth" differs a little bit from the original FPGrowth. The version in Mahout mines top-k itemsets instead of mining itemsets with the minsup threshold.